# Visual Studio 2010 solution template default location

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, templates

I have created a Visual Studio 2010 solution template that contains 2 projects, so far everything is working fine, however for some reason when I create the project the solution sits outside of the project folder, and I want it to sit inside.

This is my solution vstemplate:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="ProjectGroup">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>JWT Web Application</Name>
    <Description>ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application Boilerplate</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <TemplateGroupID>Web</TemplateGroupID>
    <NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>1</NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>
    <SortOrder>1</SortOrder>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
    <DefaultName>ClientName</DefaultName>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.png</Icon>
    <PreviewImage>__PreviewImage.png</PreviewImage>
    <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
    <PromptForSaveOnCreation>true</PromptForSaveOnCreation>
    <RequiredFrameworkVersion>4.0</RequiredFrameworkVersion>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Core">
        Boilerplate.Core\Boilerplate.Core.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Web">
        Boilerplate.Web\Boilerplate.Web.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
  <WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>Boilerplate.Wizard, Version=1.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e42ebd7a9847495c</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>Boilerplate.Wizard.RootWizard</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
</VSTemplate>
```

I then create the project:

[image: Project Screen]

Now in my inetpub directory I have the following structure:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyClientProject.sln
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyClientProject.suo
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyClientProject\
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyClientProject\MyClientProject.Core\
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyClientProject\MyClientProject.Web\

How can I set it up so the structure is like this?

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyClientProject\
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyClientProject\MyClientProject.sln
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyClientProject\MyClientProject.suo
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyClientProject\MyClientProject.Core\
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyClientProject\MyClientProject.Web\

I tried setting the  element to false, but that didn't seem to do anything. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the box that says "Create directory for solution" in order to create that sub folder.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. With `Create directory for solution` enabled it just adds a folder, but doesn't correct the file system structure. (the projects then go to `\\SolutionFolder\\SolutionFolder\\ProjectFolder` instead of `\\SolutionFolder\\ProjectFolder` and the `.sln` sits in `\\SolutionFolder` instead of `\\`)